# Frequency of combined factors and their inverse

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the frequency of pairs.

The dataframe has 2 columns of multiple factors variables like this:

```
    df
     A1 A2  
     1 "A" "A"
     2 "D" "C"
     3 "B" "A"
     4 "D" "C"
     5 "D" "C"
     6 "A" "B"
     7 "B" "A"
     8 "C" "D"
```

My data frame has hundreds of lines and 20 variables.

I have tried with the count function from plyr:

```
    count(df, c("A1", "A2"))
     A1 A2 freq
     1    A  A    1
     2    A  B    1
     3    B  A    2
     4    C  D    1
     5    D  C    3
```

But my goal is to have a result that looks like this:

```
     A1 A2 freq
     1    A  A    1
     2    A  B    3
     3    C  D    4
```

Comment: Could you explain how the goal could be calculated? It is unclear what that means in the context of your sample set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In part similar to h3rm4n solution, but only R base:

```
mat <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df, MARGIN=1, sort)))
mat$freq <- 1
aggregate( freq ~ V1 + V2, data=mat, length)

  V1 V2 freq
1  A  A    1
2  A  B    3
3  C  D    4
```

- sort each row with `apply(df, MARGIN=1, sort)` and then transpose resulting matrix and convert it to a `data.frame`
- `agggregate()` to group by the two columns and get `lenght` of each group

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
library(dplyr)
t(apply(df, 1, sort)) %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  count(A1 = V1, A2 = V2)
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  A1    A2        n
  <fct> <fct> <int>
1 A     A         1
2 A     B         3
3 C     D         4
```

Comment: @GastonCastillo Why did you unaccept my answer? Anything wrong with it?